# Why does formatting a Double using the "G" standard format string not return the full string?

Tags: c#, string-formatting, significant-digits

I hope I have researched this enough that my premise is not totally off base.  If so, then the mathematicians out there can set me straight.

My premise is that a `Double` value such as `12.5` should be rounded to 5 *significant figures* (NOT decimal places) as `12.500`.  Instead, using the following C# code, I get `12.5`:

```
Double d = 12.5;
Console.WriteLine(d.ToString("G5"));
```

I came across [this post](http://bytes.com/topic/c-sharp/answers/616344-significant-digits-double-format-strings) from 2007 which seems to echo my problem.  In fact, I am using those example numbers just to keep things consistent.

My goal here is to better understand the following:

> - Is my understanding of sig figs mathematically correct?  I.e., is my expectation reasonable, or is the output "12.5" somehow correct?
> - Is this really a (very long-lived) bug in the framework?  If so, can/will it be fixed?
> - Assuming it is a bug, what might I do about it now?  Write a hack to determine how many
>     sig figs you *actually got back* and then pad it?  Roll my own code to
>     do what the "G" format string was *supposed to do*?  I have come across examples of this on SO already, so perhaps that is evidence that a clean option does not exist.

Additionally, I do realize that the storage issues with `Double` might negatively impact the rounding aspect of this problem, but for now, I am only concerned with the issue of more sig figs than original digits.

EDIT:  I have tested this up to framework 4.5.

Comment: The value of 12.5 only *has* 3 significant figures. The precision specifies the *maximum* number of digits in the output, not the exact number of digits. I note that I was responding on the thread you refer to, with much the same thoughts as here...

Comment: @JonSkeet It does say maximum.  That escaped me at first read.  Still, I am concerned with Ben Voigt's reply that suggested that 12.500 would be the more accurate return mathematically, as it suggests greater precision to the reader.  Is that not true?  It is that suggestion of accuracy that I am attempting to convey.

Comment: While I see your point, I think the documentation that Rick quotes is the most compelling, to be honest. If you're interested in a specific number of significant digits including trailing zeroes, then you might want to look at `decimal`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See this link on [G-Format Specifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k(v=vs.110).aspx#GFormatString).  It clearly states:

> The result contains a decimal point if required, and trailing zeros after the decimal point are omitted.

Answer (score 0):

A `Double` value is rounded to 15 significant figures, not five.

Reference: [The General ("G") format specifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#GFormatString)

Rounding a number to any number of significant figures doesn't mean that the formatted string has to contain that number of digits. If the value is rounded to `12.5000000000000` then it will be formatted into `"12.5"` because that is the most compact way to represent the value.

Comment: I do understand the difference between "round to" and "significant figures".  I am suggesting that 12.500 conveys to the reader a greater precision in the value than does 12.5.  And my memory of the definition of sig figs correlates to that.  Now, C# formatting strings might not play nicely...

Comment: @DonBoitnott: The `Double` data type doesn't keep track of the preision of the value, so to show the full precision it would always be formatted to 15 significant figures. If you assigned `12.500` to the variable it would still be formatted to `12.5000000000000` because that's the precision that the data type can handle even if the input wasn't that precise.